# PayPal Instant Payment Notification warning

Tags: paypal

I received the following email from PayPal:

> Hello MyName,
>
> Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment
>   Notifications (IPN). IPNs sent to the following URL(s) are failing:
>
> URL
>
> If you do not recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider
>   that is using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider
>   with the above information. If this problem continues, IPNs may be
>   disabled for your account.
>
> Thank you for your prompt attention to this issue.
>
> Thanks,
>
> PayPal

I found [this](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/How-to-use-PayPal-Archive/PayPal-Instant-Payment-Notification-Warning/td-p/28716) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20151989/240564) and [this](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/). It's written:

> Click Profile on the My Account tab. Click Instant Payment
>   Notification Preferences in the Selling Preferences column. Click
>   Choose IPN Settings to specify your listener's URL and activate the
>   listener.

Okay, I login into PayPal, click Profile, but I can't find *Selling Preferences column* and *Instant Payment Notification Preferences*.

So I wonder what this notification means and why I received this message?

Comment: @pnuts, waht do you mean merchant? I used paypal for selling on ebay some long time ago, not now and I don't receive these strange message anymore.

Comment: @pnuts, not business account, it was primary account (something between business and personal), which allowed to take payments from credit cards. I think paypal doesn't have this type anymore. But anyway I don't use paypal for selling now.

Comment: should i delete it?

Comment: not sure I have to check my account

Comment: not primary, Premier Account – For Casual Online Sellers: [PayPal Account Types](http://pages.ebay.com.hk/eng/paypal/account_types.html)